# How do I align nodes in the forest environment?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to create a work breakdown structure as shown below using the forest package. I'm quite new to the package and am not sure exactly how the formatting of different levels work.

[image]

But my code only produces the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=6cm}, child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm}}
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        draw,
        node options={align=center,},
        text width=2.7cm,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        calign=center
    },
      where level=0{
      }{
        folder,
        grow'=0,
        if level=1{
          before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-0.75cm) -| (.child anchor)},
        }{},
        }
    [\textbf{Group E6 tasks}, minimum height=0.75cm
        [\textbf{Report}
            [\textbf{Project scope}
                [Objectives]
                [Deliverables]
                [WBS]
                [Technical requirements]
                [Limitations and exclusions]
                [Customer review and approval]
            ]
            [\textbf{Baseline}
                [Set baseline]
                [Network diagram]
            ]
            [\textbf{Budget}
                [Direct costs]
                [Training costs]
                [Overhead costs]
            ]
            [\textbf{Risk analysis}
                [Risk identification]
                [Risk response strategy]
                [Risk management plan]
            ]
        ]
        [\textbf{Simulation}
                [Resource bidding]
                [Task allocation]
                [Period submissions]
        ]
        [\textbf{Meetings}
                [Booking meeting venues]
                [Meeting minutes]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The coloring of the nodes is not important. All I need is them to be spaced out as above.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `s sep` key to increase the spacing to your taste:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=6cm}, child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm}}
        \centering
        \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        draw,
        node options={align=center,},
        text width=2.7cm,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        calign=center,
        s sep=0.5cm
    },
      where level=0{
      }{
        folder,
        grow'=0,
        if level=1{
          before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-0.75cm) -| (.child anchor)},
        }{},
        }
    [\textbf{Group E6 tasks}, minimum height=0.75cm
        [\textbf{Report}
            [\textbf{Project scope}
                [Objectives]
                [Deliverables]
                [WBS]
                [Technical requirements]
                [Limitations and exclusions]
                [Customer review and approval]
            ]
            [\textbf{Baseline}
                [Set baseline]
                [Network diagram]
            ]
            [\textbf{Budget}
                [Direct costs]
                [Training costs]
                [Overhead costs]
            ]
            [\textbf{Risk analysis}
                [Risk identification]
                [Risk response strategy]
                [Risk management plan]
            ]
        ]
        [\textbf{Simulation}
                [Resource bidding]
                [Task allocation]
                [Period submissions]
        ]
        [\textbf{Meetings}
                [Booking meeting venues]
                [Meeting minutes]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```